# Autorefresh Div-tag with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I´m trying to refresh an image every *xx* seconds, and the image already has a timestamp appended to it when the camera uploads it to the server. My solution is so far to publish the image inside a div-tag `<div id="camera">` and then refresh the div. I have tried a number of solutions that are mentioned here at Stackoverflow but I can not get them to work. Right now the code on the WP-page looks like this:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function () {
    $('#camera').fadeOut('slow').load('#camera').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000);
```

and the div that is on the webpage looks like

```
<div id="camera"><img id="kamera3" src="/webcam3/FI9804W_00626E4E4229/snap/Schedule_20140925-091319.jpg"></div>
```

Any suggestions what I should use instead? Adding random variables to the image does not work since it then only reloads the one image with the specific timestamp.

Comment: Seems like you're mixing up your IDs: `#kamera` does not exist in the given `div`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a translation gone wrong... I´ll stick to Swedish. :-)

Comment: Next problem: http://api.jquery.com/load/ - you're using it the wrong way. What do you expect to happen while executing `load()`?

Comment: Does the path change or do you just need to reload the image? In that case: `$('#kamera3').attr('src', $('#kamera3').attr('src')+'#'+rand)`; should be enough (I guess) in your interval function. Rand should be a randomly generated hash, so the browser cache is bypassed. To prevent the hashes from stacking (and making the URL too long after a while), store the original path in a data-attr and build the new url via that.

Comment: To be honest I do not know, my knowledge is very limited. This is a piece of code found in another answer that worked for that user but not for me. Basically I need help with the code between {}.

Comment: You have to know that. In case the path does not change you have to reload the same image (and avoid doing this from browser cache). If the path changes you have to do some extra effort to get the changed filename and then load the new image.

Comment: The div is a result of a php-script that fetches the latest image from an ftp folder. Hence I need to reload the div instead of the entire page. The path to the image is new with every image uploaded to the server so a random hash does not do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>hello</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var ref=setInterval(function(){  $('#camera').load('#kamera3');  }, 1000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="camera"><span id="kamera3">this is autoload function</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My text is loading, in case of image you have to tell browser to not cache image.

Comment: Ok, the above seems ok (not in Explorer however), it reloads the image but scrolls the page to the top again. Works for now! :-)

Comment: I´ve tried to edit the above set of code twice but get rejected. Anyway, you have to add /webpage/example/ to .load to get it to work, as `.load('/webbkamera/kameratest/ #kamera3')`

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` should contain an URL as first parameter (according to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)). Yours only contains `#camera` which can refer to part of the document fetched, but it still should include the document name, like so:

```
$('#camera').fadeOut('slow').load('ajax/somepage.html #camera').fadeIn("slow");
```

In the above example the page `ajax/somepage.html` will be fetched, jQuery parses it and only returns the content of the element with the id `camera`. Still, you have to provide the URL.

Comment: Thanks, but WP doesn´t return HTML pages so I can not use this type of URL?

Comment: This is the line of code that generates the div:

`<?php print '<div id="camera"><img id="kamera3" src="' .$show_file. '" alt="Webbkamera 3"></div>'; ?>`
Is it possible to refresh this instead? The .$show_file. retrievs the latest image from the ftp.

Comment: You can use any URL, as long as it returns HTML, in this case at least an `img` element. The line of code in your comment should be in a separate file you can access like `http://my-site.com/img-get.php` or in a bigger file that can provide multiple things based on a query string like so: `http://my-site.com/get.php?what=img`. Anyway, it's up to you how to work this out, but in your setup you need that URL/resource for that `load` function.